# Django Foregin Key Count

Tags: python, django-models, foreign-keys

I'm trying to get a count of the number of `Users` that are connected to a `Room`.  A `User` can be connected to only one `Room`, a `Room` can have many `Users`.

My models look like this

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Database model for users"""
    screen_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    room = models.ForeignKey(
        Room, related_name='room', on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    ...
class Room(models.Model):
    """Database model for rooms"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_full = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
```

What I'm trying to do is lock any instance of a `Room` out once a certain number of `User`s have been assigned to it.  How do I go about finding the number of `User`s connected to a given room? Pseudo code of what I'm trying.

```py
my_room.users.count >= max_users:
   my_room.is_full = True
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To get number of foreign elements you can do it like that:

```py
User.objects.filter(room=my_room).count()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     from django.db.models import Count

     def get_queryset(self):  
        queryset = User.objects.filter(room=room_id) # if you want to filter for one room
        queryset = User.objects.all() # if you want to have a list of all rooms   
        return queryset.values('room').annotate(Count('id', distinct=True)).count() # will count unique rooms
```

Comment: distinct won't work for databases different than psql.